# How to use APA7 referencing?

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

Its been a while that Ive been searching this issue here. Almost all the posts are old or cant go with my problem. The followings are my latex command that I need to be loaded:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4 paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\title{this is example}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        here is abstract.
        \noindent
        \textbf{Keywords:} classics. 
        \end{abstract}
        ]
    \section{Conclusion}
       Here is the citation \citep{Thomas}. 
    
    \bibliography{my bib file}
    
\end{document}
```

Now how do I use APA7 referencing style? I also want to cite with author name and year,  say (Thomas, 2019).
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: There isn’t a single bibliography style called “APA” — in no small part because the APA has changed its bibliography-related formatting guidelines significantly over the years. The current guidelines are frequently referred to “APA7”. Is that what you have to abide by? Or could it be “APA6”?  Please note that there’s a well-known bibliography style called `apalike`; it’s still widely used, even though it hasn’t been updated in more than 30 years. In short, please edit your posting to indicate *which* version of the APA guidelines you’re supposed to implement.

Comment: Could you please elaborate me how do I do this (staying with the referencing style like (Thomas, 2019)) ?

Comment: Depends if you are using `bibtex` or `biblatex`. If you have to use `bibtex`, the @Mico's comment about applies. If you you can use `biblatex`, then there are full-featured styles for APA7 and APA6 references.

Answer (score 2):

To transition from your current setup for creating bibliographies to one that implements the APA7 formatting guidelines, you need to

- replace

  ```
  \usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}
  ```

  where `mybibfile.bib` is the name of your bib file.
- replace

  ```
  \bibliography{mybibfile}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \printbibliography
  ```
- start using `\textcite` and `\parencite`, the `biblatex` equivalents of `natbib`'s `\citet` and `\citep` commands
- start using `biber` instead of `bibtex` to create the formatted bibliography

Be sure to run a full recompile cycle -- latex, biber, and latex -- after making these changes.

Oh, and don't use the `times` package -- it's obsolete. In fact, since you also load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages, which provide Times Roman text and math fonts, there's no discernible purpose in loading the `times` package (even if it weren't obsolete).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

% Create a bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybibfile.bib}
@misc{Thomas,
  author = "John Thomas",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%\usepackage{times} % 'times' package is obsolete
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math fonts
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{%caption, % 'caption' is loaded automatically by 'subcaption'
            subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

%%\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
%%\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} % 'backend=biber' is the default
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}


\begin{document}
\noindent
``Textual'' citation call-out: \textcite{Thomas}. 

\noindent
``Parenthetical'' citation call-out: \parencite{Thomas}.
    
%%\bibliography{mybibfile}
\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your packages, I don't really know. The package that I use for APA 7 citations is:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites, url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib} % this is your BibLatex
```

If you're using a Latex Editor, it should support Biber.

Here is the Documentation of the Package: https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf and some examples: https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf

Al least for me, with this package, no configuration is required for it to show normal APA referencing style.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. But it did not work for me. It is showing error!

Comment: Not an expert, but this worked for me: deleting the cache files generated when compiling solved the problem for me. I think that is because the file is generated witouth biber, so it fail to build it. Which editor are you using?